# Best place to put NextJs code to store certain data on localStorage when users visits site

Tags: next.js

I am working on a web application using NextJs where I intend to store some data on localStorage via javascript when a user visits my website app from any link (not primarily the index page).

**The IDEA:**
I want a process where a user visits my webapp,some certain json data would be stored in localStorage.

**Question:**

What would be the best place (considering NextJs project file structure) to put the code that will initialize this json data in localStorage?.

I think i have been overwhelmed with analysis paralysis trying to think of be best place to put the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the data to be stored within `app.js` as this initialises all other components. An example is below - the `useEffect` hook is required so that this code only runs on the client the server side of Nextjs does not have access to localstorage.

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const data = '{"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}'
    // data you want to store - JSON string in this case
    if (localStorage.getItem('data') == null) {
      localStorage.setItem('data', data) 
      // if it hasn't already been set, the localstorage variable 'data' is now set
      // access the variable anywhere else in the app with localStorage.getItem('data')
    }
  }, [])

  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```